# How to apply STL decomposition on a quarterly time series data using feasts package in R?

Tags: r, time-series, decomposition, stl-decomposition

The time series data is a quarterly sales data, that is recored in

| Date | Sales Q |
| --- | --- |
| 2019Q1 | 2000 |
| 2019Q2 | 3000 |
| 2019Q3 | 2500 |
| 2019Q4 | 3200 |

I used the `yq(date)` function to convert Date in Character into Date format. Then, I tried

```
data %>%
model(feasts::STL(Actual, robust = TRUE)
```

It resulted in an error

```
[1] .data contains implicit gaps in time. You should check your data and convert implicit gaps into explicit missing values using `tsibble::fill_gaps()` if required.
```

Even I used `fill_gap(data)`, it will not work.

How can I apply `STL()` on this kind of data?

Comment: Try using `tsibble::yearquarter()` to create your time index. The error occurs when you have some gaps (missing quarters) in your data, you will need to replace them with a suitable value to use STL. Note that fill_gaps() isn't enough, as it uses NA and STL doesn't support missing (NA) values. You can replace the NA with tidyr::fill() or some other appropriate interpolation method.

Comment: I have already tried, not work

Comment: Actually, if we use `year quarter()` we should meet the same issue.

Comment: COuld you please share your data using `dput`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is quite simple, just using `tsibble::year_quarter(yq(Date))`